# How to clear all associated tasks?

Tags: android

I have a module integrated into my app that has its own Activities and back stack. While getting some event back from the module, I am not able to clear my stack and end up on Activity that invoked module means module's stack got cleared but mine app's not.

I am calling below method to clear the stack.

> finishAffinity();

Is there any way I can clear/remove all tasks associated with my application because I think at least two tasks have been created in my application due to the addition of module. Any help is appreciated.

PS- After further debugging, I found it was only one task where all my app's and added module's activities were getting added.

Comment: So, you are in your app activity, you start an activity from your module and after a while you want to finish all activities that belong to the module. Is this correct?

Comment: @Ricardo yes I want to finish all activities associated with my application whether they belong to the module or my app. The module takes care of its stack and able to finish its activities, but I am not maybe because multiple tasks are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that all my activities were added to a single task and we can remove task by calling below method-

```
finishAndRemoveTask()
```

[More](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.AppTask.html#finishAndRemoveTask())

This is how we can check in terminal activity stack and associated task-

```
adb shell dumpsys activity activities
```